How to display average ratings in the form of stars in django
I want to display the average rating on a product in the form of stars where i want to have 5 stars and then fill the stars with gold color on how much the average rating on the product is.
This is my code and my relation b/w models
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    digital = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    sizes =  models.ManyToManyField(Size, through='ProductSize')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
    
    @property
    def get_average_rating(self):
        average = self.comment_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
        if average is not None:
            return round(average, 1)
        else:
            return 0 


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/comment_images', null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)])

I tried to run a loop like this but it did not work as the average rating is in float
I do not know much javascript so if you can help me in js that will be appreciated too thank you!!
           {% for _ in product.get_average_rating %}
               &#9733;
           {% endfor %}


What you want i think is more related with javascript and CSS in the template. Here i found some code that i think it can help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_star_rating.asp

Render it in the model:
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    digital = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, through='ProductSize')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def average_rating(self):
        return round(
            self.comment_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg'] or 0, 1
        )

    @property
    def star_rating(self):
        return '★' * self.average_rating
and render with:
{{ product.star_rating }}
